# OpenLayers - Mosaic of custom images on one layer

Tags: javascript, image, openlayers

Is it possible to have a layer made up of a mosaic of custom images?

I've been only able to get a single custom image on a given layer via `OpenLayers.Layer.Image`. Essentially, if I could find a way to specify custom images for the tiles of a given layer, then my problem would be solved.

I have tried various combinations of `OpenLayers.Tile`, `OpenLayers.Tile.Image`, `OpenLayers.Layer` and `OpenLayers.Layer.Grid` but haven't been able to things working.

The basic flow I follow is:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

var layer = new <OpenLayers.Layer | OpenLayers.Layer.Grid> (<parameters>);

var tile1 = new <OpenLayers.Tile | OpenLayers.Tile.Image> (<parameters>);

map.addLayer(layer);

map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```

Specific examples of how I initialize each constructor are provided below.

Regarding `OpenLayers.Layer.Grid`, I'm actually not sure what to specify for the url and params constructor parameters.

Any advice on whether this works and/or if I'm on the right track would be greatly appreciated.

**OpenLayers.Layer**

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer(
  'layer_name',
  {
    isBaseLayer: true
  }
);
```

**OpenLayers.Layer.Grid**

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Grid(
  'layer_name',
  ?url?,
  ?params?
);
```

**OpenLayers.Tile**

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Tile(
  layer_name,
  new OpenLayers.Pixel(0,0),
  new OpenLayers.Bounds(-1,-1,1,1),
  'square1.jpg',
  new OpenLayers.Size(300,300)
);
```

**OpenLayers.Tile.Image**

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Tile.Image(
  layer_name,
  new OpenLayers.Pixel(0,0),
  new OpenLayers.Bounds(-1,-1,1,1),
  new OpenLayers.Size(300,300),
  {
    url: 'square1.jpg'
  }
);
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Are you trying to show arbitrary images in a grid which are not actually tiles of a single image? I'm trying to do something like this because I'm using OpenLayers for something completely unrelated to maps/GIS and am wondering whether this is even possible/desired without naming files in a funny way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Zoomify layer? Here's the [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/zoomify.html). It allows you to load in the map all images from a given directory, named in the form `{z}-{x}-{y}.jpg`, where `{z}` is the zoom level.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to break up an image into smaller tiles, I suggest using this free [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.org/) software, which will create the tiles for as many zoom levels as you need.

You can create a map layer of image tiles using a TMS Layer:

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS("TMS Layer","",
    {url: '', serviceVersion: '.', layername: '.', alpha: true,
     type: 'png', getURL: getTileURL 
    }
);
map.addLayer(layer);
```

The `getTileURL` function is used by the TMS layer to find the tiled images to display.   This function assumes that the images are stored in a hierarchical structure like the one created by [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.org/).
Ex: img/tiles/7/4/1.png is the image that is 5th from the left and 2nd from the bottom of zoom level 7.

```
function getTileURL(bounds) 
{
    var res = this.map.getResolution();
    var x = Math.round((bounds.left - this.maxExtent.left) / (res * this.tileSize.w));
    var y = Math.round((bounds.bottom - this.maxExtent.bottom) / (res * this.tileSize.h));
    var z = this.map.getZoom();

    var path = "img/tiles/" + z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type;
    var url = this.url;
    if (url instanceof Array) 
    {
        url = this.selectUrl(path, url);
    }
    return url + path;
}
```